# Find the coordinates of the rotation origin

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Let's say I have a point $P$ located at the end of an arm of a known length $L$. I know the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of P after it has been rotated around the origin, which is located at the other end of the arm. I also have the 3x3 rotation matrix.

For context, the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates come from a GPS mounted on a drone (and have been transformed to local coordinates), while the rotation data is from a sensor located in the center of a drone. The distance between these points is $L$ and is known.

Having this information, how can I determine the coordinates $(a,b,c)$ of the origin of rotation, i.e. the center of the drone?

Comment: What's the exact meaning of the rotation matrix? What does it rotate? Does it assume that you rotate say $(0,0,L)$ to some $(x,y,z)$? Or is it $(L,0,0)$? Or some other vector?

Comment: @Andrei The frame of reference origin (0,0,0) is different from the rotation origin (i.e. the point I am looking for). I have the rotation matrix calculated from the quaternion from the drone's IMU angle readings (at the rotation origin). I guess I could say that **P** has been translated by **L** from the center in the Z axis, and then rotated around the center?

Comment: And then translated by $(a,b,c)$. You can find the full answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $(x,y,z)$ position is given by $$(x,y,z)^T=(a,b,c)^T+R(0,0,L)^T$$
That means that when the drone is at the origin, and the rotation matrix is the identity, then the point $P$ is at $(0,0,L)$. From the above equation you can then get $(a,b,c)$ by moving the rotation term to the other side.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like exactly what I needed.